# MySQL database re-orders entries automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a MySQL database using MySQL Workbench. In there, I have created a table, the first entries of which are:

```
id     firstName     lastName
1      John          Smith
2      Emma          Richards
```

Every column contains VARCHAR characters - even the id, it is NOT an integer.
For some reason, however, MySQL seems to re-order the entries:

```
id     firstName     lastName
1      John          Smith
10     Karen         Hill
```

I don't want MySQL to re-order my entries. When I retrieve the entries from the database, I want them to appear exactly in the order that I have inserted them into the database.
Previously to creating the MySQL database, I have used a SQLite database, which does not re-order the entries.

What might be the reason for this and how can I change it?

Comment: Tables are inherently unsorted, you can only get a guaranteed order if you use `ORDER BY`

Comment: use the order by clause to sort (ascending or descending) by id? without the order by clause, the db is not supposed to sort, hence the result is not sorted.

Comment: Why id is not integer when you prefer ordeing by int value rather then lexigraphic string ordering?

Comment: On the ORDER BY: Of course `'1' < '10' < '2'` whereas `1 < 2 < 10`. (Should that relate to your question.)

Comment: id is a VARCHAR, because it could (theoretically) be any combination of characters. That's also why I don't want the entries to be ordered. I just want them to appear in the order that I have added them to the database. If tables are inherently unsorted, this should be the case, shouldn't it? It is not though.

Comment: @Luk, no. Tables are inherently unsorted means when no `order by` provided in the query rows could be returned in any order db engine decides it is faster to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want MySQL to re-order my entries. When I retrieve the entries from the database, I want them to appear exactly in the order that I have inserted them into the database.

SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  Period.  When you query a table in any database, the ordering is not guaranteed unless you include an `order by`.  This is even true in SQLite, as [this DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ffd944f16344bd79be371e89d3bbb603) demonstrates.

In most databases, if you want to capture the insertion order, then you need some sort of column that captures the ordering.  There are two common methods:

- An `identity` or `auto_increment` column that captures the insertion order.
- A datetime/timestamp column that captures the date time.  This does not always work, because there can be ties.

Then, when you query the table, you need to use `order by` on the column.

If your first column represents the ordering but happens to be stored as a string, then you can simply use:

```
order by (id + 0)
```